# Exit Do-Until Loop with any key

Tags: powershell, keypress, do-loops

I want to create a simple loop until user presses any key. The goal is that the loops stop only if any key is pressed. Otherwise loop and loop and loop without any interaction. I think my code will tell you what I'am want. But I am not sure if this solveable with this type of loop?

```
$sec = 0
Write-Host 'Press any key to quit...'

do {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$sec Sec"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $sec ++    
} until ($null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[System.Console]::KeyAvailable`. It will return a value, once a key press is available in the input stream.

```
$sec = 0 
do 
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$sec Sec"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $sec++    

} until ([System.Console]::KeyAvailable)
```

Once you press any key, this will end the loop as soon as the loop condition is evaluated.

Comment: so simple... :) Thank you so much!